# How to resolve ? com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 3 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, exception, utf-8, malformed

I am using `parse()` method of DocumentBuilder class in my code.

> - Document doc = dBuilder.parse(bis);

On above line it is throwing below exception :

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 3 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
       at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
       at org.econ.alm.client.AbstractALMClient.getEntitiesBMD(AbstractALMClient.java:226)
       at org.econ.alm.extracter.MDBTestExtractor.run(MDBTestExtractor.java:204)
       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If anyone is aware of the root cause and solution, Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML parsing error related to char encoding set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886439/xml-parsing-error-related-to-char-encoding-set)

Comment: You did not explain what `bis` is, or what it contains. I am guessing it is a `ByteInputStream`, is that right? Clearly the XML content of `bis` is either not UTF-8 encoded, or is malformed UTF-8.  Otherwise you would not be getting the error in the first place.  So double-check the encoding of your source data.

Comment: bis is a ByteArrayInputStream.This issue was solved by setting parameters in  eclipse under Windows->Perspective.Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked changing the parse function: from file XML to InputSource (changing charset to UTF)

```
 InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file); 
 Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");        
 InputSource is = new InputSource(reader); 
 is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
 doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```